# Network usage when doing remote Sonar analysis via Maven?

Tags: maven, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I'm working in a corporation with global offices and distributed development teams connected via a corporate WAN. Each team has traditionally committed their code to a local (to them) SVN repository and ran build jobs on a local Jenkins build server.

What I want to do is set up a single SonarQube installation for doing code analysis for these distributed projects. However, the WAN connecting these offices is a shared resource and we often get flack from our infrastructure team for over-using it.

All our maven projects are now configured to initiate sonar analysis via the "mvn sonar:sonar" target, it all seems to work fine. My question is, how much network resources does the sonarqube maven runner need to do analysis for a single maven project? I'm trying to ascertain whether I should set up separate Sonarqube instances for every region (which is painful).

When running a the mvn sonar:sonar target, I see the following on the command line:

```
[INFO] [09:00:01.755] CPD calculation finished
[INFO] [09:00:02.077] Analysis report generated in 291ms, dir size=236 KB
[INFO] [09:00:02.497] Analysis reports compressed in 420ms, zip size=111 KB
[INFO] [09:00:04.408] Analysis report uploaded in 1911ms
```

If that is the only data uploaded during the analysis, then it should be OK to run the SonarQube server remotely.

Do you know if there is any other reasonable network traffic generated by this process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main network traffic generated by a SonarQube analysis is:

- a couple of GET HTTP requests at the very beginning to retrieve all the settings and context of the project
- a POST request at the end of the analysis to upload the report to the SonarQube server

If the teams are not doing a SonarQube analyses every minute, then you should be fine with the network usage.